Why do duplicate elements in a SwiftUI array cause a warning?
For a word game, I am using .map to create an array of the letters of a guessed word,
for example:
var guessWordArray = "BALANCE".map{String($0)}

which creates the array
["B", "A", "L", "A", "N", "C", "E"]

but then I get the warning,

"...the ID A occurs multiple times within the collection, this will give undefined results."

I don't understand why an array with duplicate elements would "give undefined results." Is this an improper use of an array? Is there an alternative I should use?
I would expect an array not to 'care' what elements are in it and whether they are all the same, different, or any mix. I am obviously missing something.

You are probably using this array in a ForEach(guessWordArray, id: \.self) {...} and
this is where the values of the array needs to be unique.  See  ForEach  says "...elements must conform to Identifiable or you need to provide an id parameter to the ForEach initializer ..."

See the answer to How to dynamically populate a SwiftUI Picker (segmented control) for a way to solve: by using .enumerated() with .offset as id.

The warning message is quite explicit. Looking at the documentation about ForEach, this component needs a unique ID to distinguish the elements that are passed in. In this scenario, you're passing string itself by \.self.

["B", "A", "L", "A", "N", "C", "E"]

You can see "A" character appears twice within the array, that's why the warning occurs.

As @workingdog mentioned above, you need to create a model that fully conforms to Identifiable, something like:
struct CharacterElement: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var value: String
}

After that, you're able to remove \.self within ForEach:
var words = "BALANCE".map { CharacterElement(value: String($0)) }

var body: some View {
    ForEach(words) {
        //TODO:
    }
}


Thank you @son. I realize it's the 'A' that is duplicated in the example and generating the warning. I see now from your answer and working dog that it's the ForEach that is the problem, and this now makes sense to me. Thanks so much.
